# Cannot uninstall open3d in ubuntu20.04 by using pip uninstall

Tags: python, pip, ubuntu-20.04, open3d

im trying to uninstall open3d pkg from my ubuntu 20.04 but it didn't work well

by using
`pip uninstall open3d`

```
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 791, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/etc/jupyter/nbconfig/notebook.d/open3d.json' -> '/tmp/pip-uninstall-r1n2ooyx/open3d.json'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tharit/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 180, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
  File "/home/tharit/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/uninstall.py", line 105, in run
    uninstall_pathset = req.uninstall(
  File "/home/tharit/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 725, in uninstall
    uninstalled_pathset.remove(auto_confirm, verbose)
  File "/home/tharit/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_uninstall.py", line 381, in remove
    moved.stash(path)
  File "/home/tharit/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_uninstall.py", line 272, in stash
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/home/tharit/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 362, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 812, in move
    os.unlink(src)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/etc/jupyter/nbconfig/notebook.d/open3d.json'
```

I'm not sure about how to solve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converted comment to answer.

Try `sudo pip uninstall open3d` the directory is probably owned by root.